# How to install an application manually in the /data

Tags: samsung

My problem is that I want to be able to install an application manually without the help of the android system, ie I want to be able to install an application by copying the apk, dex and data files in the data directories, and be able to present the application as installed. Because I copied the files previously and the application does not appear as installed, if not until I restart the device.

The purpose of my question is to learn more about the system I use the most famous Android

If you know of any way to help me, I'll be happy to hear from you. Thank you

Comment: Anyway even if you correctly put the files into the right place, you still need `PackageManager` to update its database. And on every boot PM automatically scans for new packages that's not found before, so you may still have to reboot.

Comment: Installing an app involves more than just placing random files somewhere on the `data` partition. In short: each app get's its own user and group id, SEAndroid context, entry in the app database mapped to the internal user id, optimizing the DEX file for the hardware to either ODEX or OAT, scanning for launchable activities, registering broadcast handler etc. You can't even do half of these actions manually because of the sheer complexity. Let the package manager handle everything for you, it's there for a reason.